# Firefox - deactivate "open with Application" to prevent system manipulation

Tags: firefox

I am using firefox in an security system. There is an option under Preferences --> Applications that alows the user to define what url will be opened in which application.

For example: mailto: will open Outlook. You can also define other keywords to open an application.

Is there a way to block this preferences? Script/Config what ever.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use a sandboxing solution that prevents firefox from acessing or executing those external applications. On linux you can use [firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/) and configure it accordingly.